# Differentiate categories from tags in a Wordpress RSS feed

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, rss, feed

I have a wordpress blog with an automatic generated rss feed (https://blog.pixelinnova.com/feed), but I can't find a way to differentiate the categories from the tags, they are all between the XML tags `<category></category>`. For example:

```
<category><![CDATA[Consultoría tecnológica]]></category>
<category><![CDATA[Marketing digital]]></category>
<category><![CDATA[centennials]]></category>
<category><![CDATA[facebook]]></category>
```

The two first ones are categories, the others are tags.

Is there a way that I can make them look different in the feed, like changing the tags' "category" XML tag or something?

[image: Example image]

The ones marked in yellow are categories. The others are tags.

Comment: The "category" XML tag is a part of RSS 2.0 specification: https://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/rss2.html. Changing the tag could probably break your feed for consumers.

Tags are added as categories because WordPress treats them like that.

If you really want to change that, you can either use a custom RSS plugin or directly edit the `get_the_category_rss` function in `wp-includes/feed.php`.

Still, why do you want to change it?

Comment: I am developing a custom app where the users can check the blog news from some of my wordpress pages, and I wanted to offer a category filter, but just with the main categories, not the tags. All of this I take from the RSS, but on testing, I found that the filters were showing about 20 categories instead of the 3 or 4 that I expected, so I need to find a way to diferentiate them, or manage so the tags don't even appear in the RSS. I'll check the plugin and the function you told me. Thanks!

Comment: Got it. Another note, please avoid editing the core WordPress files since they can be overwritten by an update. You may want to write a custom filter instead: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/171945/24585
Please note the return statement of `get_the_category_rss` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a snippet that makes only categories appear on the feed, I added it to the functions.php on my child theme and it worked:

```
add_filter('get_the_tags', 'strip_tags_from_feeds');
function strip_tags_from_feeds($terms) {
if (is_feed())
  return array();
  return $terms;
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was searching about.